# Trying to delete node causes seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a multi-thread for inserting elements into a doubly linked list from a command file but when it tries to remove the node from beginning of the list it throws a seg fault and I can't determine why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <semaphore.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0

typedef int bool;

typedef struct commandnode  //struct for command list
{
  struct commandnode *prevcommand;
  char *a;
  int key;
  struct commandnode *nextcommand;
  pthread_mutex_t commandlock;
} commandnode;

typedef struct Node
{
  struct Node *prev;
  int n;
  struct Node *next;
  pthread_mutex_t lock;
} Node;

typedef struct List
{
  int size;
  commandnode *head;
  commandnode *tail;
  Node *tailer;
  Node *header;
} List;

int search(int);
void create(int);
void insert(List, int);
void delete(List, int);
void printList(List);
void printEle(List, int);

void createcommand(char[], int);
void insertcommand(List, char[], int);
void printcommandList();
commandnode removecommand(List);

int nodecount = 0;
sem_t fill;
sem_t empty;
int emptyed = 5;
int filled = 0;

List* buffer;
List* line;

void* doSomeThing(void *arg)
{
  int value, i;
  char *command;
  commandnode *tempcommand = malloc(sizeof(commandnode));
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    sem_wait(&fill);
    //printcommandList(*buffer);
    //printf("|");
    *tempcommand = removecommand(*buffer);
    //command=tempcommand->a;
    //value=tempcommand->key;
    sem_post(&empty);

  }
  return 0;
}

int main(int paramcount, char* paramstr[])
{
  FILE *infile;
  pthread_t *thread;
  int workers = 1;
  int err, slot, i, k;
  sem_init(&empty, 0, workers);
  sem_init(&fill, 0, 0);
  if (paramcount != 1)
  {
    printf("Incorrect number of parameters");
    return 1;
  }

  thread = (pthread_t *) malloc(workers * sizeof(pthread_t)); //creating theads

  buffer = calloc(1, sizeof(List));
  buffer->head = calloc(1, sizeof(commandnode));
  buffer->tail = calloc(1, sizeof(commandnode));
  buffer->head->nextcommand = buffer->tail;
  buffer->tail->prevcommand = buffer->head;

  line = calloc(1, sizeof(List));
  line->header = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
  line->tailer = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
  line->header->next = line->tailer;
  line->tailer->prev = line->header;

  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
  {
    slot = i;
    err = pthread_create(&(thread[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, &slot);
    if (err != 0)
      printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
    //else
    //printf("thread created");
  }

  infile = fopen("fscanftest.txt", "r");

  if (infile == NULL )
  {
    printf("Error opening file.\n");
    return 2;
  }

  int inputs = 0;
  int key;
  //while(inputs==0){ 
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    char command[40];
    char *commands = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
    fscanf(infile, "%s", command);
    strcpy(commands, command);
    /*if(strcmp(command,"exit")==0){
     key=0;
     for(k=0;k<workers;k++){
     sem_wait (&empty);
     insertcommand(*buffer,commands,key);        
     sem_post(&fill);
     }
     inputs=1;
     }
     else{*/
    if (strcmp(command, "insert") == 0 || strcmp(command, "delete") == 0
        || strcmp(command, "read") == 0)
    {
      fscanf(infile, "%d", &key);
    }
    else
    {
      key = 0;
    }
    sem_wait(&empty);
    insertcommand(*buffer, commands, key);
    sem_post(&fill);
    //sem_getvalue(&empty,&k);
    //printf("%d",k);
    //sem_getvalue(&fill,&k);
    //printf("(%d)",k);

    //}

  }
  //printcommandList(*buffer);

  int c;
  for (c = 0; c < 1; c++)
    pthread_join(thread[c], NULL );
  return 1;
}

void insertcommand(List list, char* command, int sendkey)
{
  commandnode *tempcommand = malloc(sizeof(commandnode));

  pthread_mutex_lock(&list.tail->commandlock);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&list.tail->prevcommand->commandlock);

  tempcommand->prevcommand = list.tail->prevcommand;
  tempcommand->nextcommand = list.tail;
  tempcommand->prevcommand->nextcommand = tempcommand;
  list.tail->prevcommand = tempcommand;
  tempcommand->a = command;
  tempcommand->key = sendkey;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&list.tail->commandlock);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&list.tail->prevcommand->prevcommand->commandlock);

}
commandnode removecommand(List list)
{

  commandnode *tempcommand = malloc(sizeof(commandnode));
  pthread_mutex_lock(&list.head->commandlock);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&list.head->nextcommand->commandlock);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&list.head->nextcommand->nextcommand->commandlock);

  tempcommand = list.head->nextcommand;
  //printf(" %s %d ",tempcommand->a,tempcommand->key); 
  list.head->nextcommand = tempcommand->nextcommand; // found the seg falut happens here
  list.head->nextcommand->prevcommand = list.head;
  list.head->nextcommand->prevcommand = list.head;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&list.head->commandlock);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&list.head->nextcommand->commandlock);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&list.head->nextcommand->nextcommand->commandlock);

  return *tempcommand;
}

void printcommandList(List list)
{
  commandnode *tempcommand = malloc(sizeof(commandnode));
  //pthread_mutex_lock(&list.head->commandlock);
  // pthread_mutex_lock(&list.head->nextcommand->commandlock);

  tempcommand = list.head->nextcommand;

  //pthread_mutex_unlock(&list.head->commandlock);

  while (tempcommand->nextcommand != list.tailer)
  {
    printf(" %s ", tempcommand->a);
    printf(" %d ", tempcommand->key);

    //  pthread_mutex_lock(&tempcommand->nextcommand->commandlock);
    tempcommand = tempcommand->nextcommand;
    //  pthread_mutex_unlock(&tempcommand->prevcommand->commandlock);   
  }
  //pthread_mutex_unlock(&tempcommand->prevcommand->nextcommand->commandlock);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You malloc `tempcommand` and then you leak it:

```
commandnode *tempcommand = malloc(sizeof(commandnode)); // **malloc****
pthread_mutex_lock(&list.head->commandlock);
pthread_mutex_lock(&list.head->nextcommand->commandlock);
pthread_mutex_lock(&list.head->nextcommand->nextcommand->commandlock);

tempcommand=list.head->nextcommand; // **leak**
//printf(" %s %d ",tempcommand->a,tempcommand->key); 
list.head->nextcommand=tempcommand->nextcommand; // found the seg falut happens here
```

The seg fault is probably because `tempcommand` is 0. You probably did not want the assignment where the leak is.

Comment: Then why dose the printf command work if the tempcommand is 0?

Comment: Run it in the debugger until it seg faults, then print the value of tempcommand. Bet you it's 0. If it's not 0, then I think your seg fault happens someplace else.